# What is this SMD component, marked as D7 with an underline?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

[image: What is this SMD component?]

I'm trying to identify the SMD component (marked as D7 with an underline) on a circuit board of an ARGB LED controller. I think it is a diode or resistor, but I'm not sure about it. Please can I get some help with identifying it?

Comment: It looks like it has a designator, "F2", which would make it most likely a ferrite bead.

Comment: @ThePhoton Isn't F more common for fuses, with ferrite beads marked FB?

Comment: The D7 just the manufactures code on the component. It doesn't mean anything unless you know who made it and what it is and then look up what the marking codes mean.

It's component F2 on the PCB. Which probably means it is a fuse, or at least a component that is being used in the role of a fuse.

Comment: This is a duplicate question . Search next time

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A resistance check could determine if it's a diode. It should exhibit a different resistance in each direction. A fuse would provide a short in both directions. "D" is very commonly used as a reference designator for diodes, but that is NOT a hard and fast rule.

Comment: The D7 is not the reference designator, it's the actual part marking. The reference designator is F2.

Answer (score 19):

That looks like an LP-USML400 resettable "polyfuse" made by Way-On.
Datasheet [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://way-on.cn/UploadFile/Product/LP-USM_L_series201505.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjSspKa2LDiAhXjQd8KHWB4BuIQFjAAegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw2266C0ba23inS2Il2W8HB2)

Comment: Holds 4A trips 8A

Answer (score 3):

[image]
D7 with mark F2, It's a Fast tripping resettable circuit protection.

http://way-on.cn/products/detail.aspx?id=597

Answer (score 2):

The F2 next to it designates this as a fuse.... F1 is green

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be a fuse. Looks identical to the one to the 12V pin from [this](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/959130-cooler-master-h500m-front-panel-io-not-working/).

Comment: yeah it the same one since it's from the same brand "cooler master" so it i guess it is a fuse, thanks for you answer @NeptBlu7

Answer (score 0):

D is used for diode in most cases by various techies. however not sure about under line representation,

Comment: The D7 is not the reference designator, it's the actual part marking. The reference designator is F2.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fuse for sure. We always designate ferrite beads with FB.